# How can I merge with a remote repository, and undo what it adds?

Tags: git, github

I work collaboratively with a friend on a personal project, and he maintains a separate GitHub repository from me. I am marked as a contributor to his repository. I have been making some changes ahead of him, and they render one of his commits unnecessary - we don't need the code. I have already committed my changes to my repository, but I have not yet pushed them to his.

I plan on pulling his changes in order to merge with mine, but is the only solution to this problem that I promptly delete every line of code in question? I hope that Git solves this problem another way, as this approach might upset him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things can help you here.  If your friend's changes are on a branch, and you want to merge the branch to keep his changes alive in the graph, you can

```
git merge -s ours his-branch
```

If his commit is on master, already pushed, and just needs to go away, you can

```
git revert his-commit
```

...making a new commit that un-does his changes.  In either case, you merge your changes (explicitly with the command that is the first case, or with an additional `git merge` in the second case) and then push the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you git pull = git fetch + git Merge Fetch_head. Assuming you guys are working on the same branch, any changes he has made will merge with your changes. If you have made changes in the same place, there will be conflict at which point you can simply resolve the conflict by deleting his code. If not you guys can create a new branch, using `git branch <branch-name> <commit id>` off of the commit before he added the unnecessary commits and then merge your code onto this branch and continue working from there.

Answer (score 1):

> but is the only solution to this problem that I promptly delete every line of code in question?

Suppose you both started working from commit A. You made commit B ahead of him.

1. If the unnecessary code is already in A's tree, presumably B deletes this code so just merging is enough.
2. If he committed the unnecessary code in a separate commit C and you don't have C, just discard C or merge and revert C.

> I hope that Git solves this problem another way, as this approach might upset him.

This is not a problem that Git can solve. If your friend cannot handle his code being removed, there is no technology known to mankind that will deliver a satisfactory resolution.